# Summarize by multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I `summarize` this `df` by `time` and `country` using `dplyr`?

```
df <- data.frame(sex     = c("MALE","FEMALE","MALE","FEMALE"),
                 time    = c("2018","2018","2019","2019"),
                 country = c("USA","USA","USA","USA"),
                 value   = c(10,10,10,10))
df %>% group_by(c(time, country)) %>% summarize(sumval = sum(value))
```

I am having

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 4.
```

Expected result:

```
    TIME    Country   Value
1   2018    USA       20
2   2019    USA       20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove `c(…)` around your group names:

```r
df %>% group_by(time, country) %>%
    summarize(sumval = sum(value), .groups = 'drop')
```

(`.groups = 'drop'` is unnecessary but as of ‘dplyr’ 1.0 you’ll get a warning otherwise.)

Comment: what is this `.groups` argument used for?

Comment: @CatalystRPA [Check the documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html): it controls whether `summarize` ungroups the table or not.